# 横スクロールと画像縮小をしたい

Tags: android, java

画像を複数枚並べて、横スクロールで見れるようにしたいです。
今、一枚の画像が大きすぎて、一枚しか見えない状態です。なので、画像を小さくしたく、Bitmapというメソットを使い、HorizontalScrollViewのコードを追加したのですが、エラーが出てしまいました。
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command というエラーが出ました。

activity_main.xml では

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>　⬅︎

<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    　　android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    　　android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    　>　⬅︎

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="yurihasuike.teamgirls.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bigfig"
        android:src="@drawable/bigfig" />

    <ImageView
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/feminine"
        android:src="@drawable/feminine" />


</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>　⬅︎
```

のように記述し⬅︎の部分でエラーが出ました。

MainActivity.javaでは

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView imageView1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.feminine);
        ImageView imageView2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.bigfig);

        Resources res = getResources();

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.bigfig);

        // bitmapの画像を200×90で作成する
        Bitmap bitmap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 200, 45, false);

        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.feminine);

        // bitmapの画像を200×90で作成する
        Bitmap bitmap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 200, 45, false);

        img.setImageBitmap(bitmap2);



//        imageView2.setImageResource(R.drawable.bigfig);
    }


    }
```

のように記述しました。
Bitmapの記述の仕方がおかしかったのでしょうか？
また、画像の大きさを変えるメソットはBitmapであっていますか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

いくつかの質問の複合になっていますが、問題点をひとつに絞ると回答しやすいと思います。

### レイアウトXMLのエラーが出る

> Error:(4) Error parsing XML: not well-formed (invalid token)

というエラーメッセージがでていないでしょうか？

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: Failed to execute aapt

こちらのエラーは、GradleのAndroidプラグインのタスク`:app:processDebugResources`が失敗したことを示すメッセージで、本質的なエラーの内容ではありません。

実際のエラー原因はXMLのパースに失敗していることで、見たところでは全角スペースが入っているためのように思えます。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/bigfig"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/bigfig" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/feminine"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/feminine" />
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

ですので、全角スペースを削除すればエラーは消えると思います。

`fill_parent`の記法は古いので`match_parent`を使っています。また、`LinearLayout`の`xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`のスキーマ宣言は重複しているので、削除しています。

## 画像のサイズを変えたい

`Bitmap`はメソッドではなくクラスになります。

`Bitmap#createScaledBitmap()`でリサイズする方法は間違ってはいないですが、ほとんどの場合、[`ThumbnailUtils`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ThumbnailUtils.html)を用いた方が簡単に記述できます。

また、[`ImageView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html)自体に画像をリサイズして表示する機能がありますので、`ImageView`の横幅と高さを目的のサイズにして、そこへ画像をセットするという方法もあります。スケーリング方法は、`scaleType`で指定できます。

※ただし、元画像が大きすぎる場合にはメモリを逼迫する可能性があるため、`Bitmap`のリサイズと併用する必要もあるでしょう。

## 画像を複数枚並べて、横スクロールで見れるようにしたい

この場合、どのような表示にしたいのかにもよるので一概には言えませんが、`HorizontalScrollView`よりも[`ViewPager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)の方が好ましいように思えます。

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPager"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ImageView.ScaleType;

import static android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int[] drawables = {
            R.drawable.bigfig,
            R.drawable.feminine
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter() {

            @Override
            public ImageView instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                ImageView imageView = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
                imageView.setImageDrawable(getDrawable(drawables[position]));
                container.addView(imageView, new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(MATCH_PARENT, MATCH_PARENT));
                return imageView;
            }

            @Override
            public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
                if (object instanceof ImageView) {
                    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) object;
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
                    container.removeView(imageView);
                }
                super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return drawables.length;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                return view == object;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`ViewPager`の詳細な使い方については、参考になるリファレンスが多々あると思いますので省略します。